# Regex to find all words that start with @ but ignore email addresses

Tags: asp.net, regex

I created this regex to match all words that start with "@" in my string, there could be something before the @ tokens as well. it works well but it also catches email addresses and i would like to fix that.

```
(?<=@)\w+\b
```

Example string would be:

> hello @bob, how are you? @mark, @emma and @chief are with me. email me
>   at test@email.com!

Can you help?

Comment: Well you can check if the string contains a "." after the "@" but that doesnt necessarily mean that you're dealing with an email address. I am thinking about "a@b" for istance. Quite a good question I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the next expression:

```
\B@\w+
```

which starts at a [non-word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\B`). You could also rewrite it using [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like this:

```
(?!\b)@\w+
```

Answer (score 0):

Test for the space in front of the @

Comment: thanks @Sprachprofi but like i said in my question, there could be a space there or not

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is this.

> `[\s]?\B@\w+`

I've tested it in Regex Designer from RAD Software and it matches every word that starts with an @. With or without a space in front of it.

Hope this helped ;)

Comment: But it also matches a space before the word: " @bob", " @mark", " @emma" and " @chief" will be matched in the example string (with an extra space).

Comment: isnt that what what he asked? :p